# How can I update a heatmap on a GUI when I change the input values

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to display a GUI with a heatmap and scales/sliders with the scales/sliders changing the values in the heatmap.

I can display the heatmap and sliders and can read from the sliders but I cannot get the heat map to update after I have moved the sliders.

I have tried putting the code (I think) updates the heatmap in a function which is called whenever the scale/slider is moved but I am clearly missing something.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

def myFunc(value):
    print (mySlider.get())
    array[1][2]=mySlider.get()

    #I think I need to put something here to update the heatmap when the
    #scale/slider is changed but do not know what
    figure, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(array)

    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()                           


    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("Something")

array = ([[1,2,3,4],
          [3,9,1,5],
          [8,4,1,7],
          [2,4,9,1]])

figure, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(array)

canvas = plt.Figure()                   
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, root)                
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()                           

mySlider = tkinter.Scale(root, from_=0, to=15, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=myFunc)
mySlider.pack()
```

Comment: You create a new figure each time the slider moves. Instead you should update the existing figure. For a start I would recommend you stick to [the official example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) and modify it step by step.

Comment: Can you tell me which line is creating the new figure?

Comment: `figure, ax = plt.subplots()` creates a new figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

def myFunc(value):
    print (mySlider.get())
    array[1][2]=mySlider.get()

    im.set_array(array)
    canvas.draw()                        


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Something")

array = ([[1,2,3,4],
          [3,9,1,5],
          [8,4,1,7],
          [2,4,9,1]])

figure, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(array)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, root)                
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()                           

mySlider = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=15, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=myFunc)
mySlider.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

However tkinter is not needed here. matplotlib has a slider built in (I assume you know since you imported it) which is a lot easier to implement:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

def myFunc(value):
    array[1][2]=value
    im.set_array(array)

array = ([[1,2,3,4],
          [3,9,1,5],
          [8,4,1,7],
          [2,4,9,1]])

figure, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(array)                        
ax_slider = plt.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.03]) # [left, bottom, width, height]
slide = Slider(ax_slider, '', 0, 15, valinit=0)
slide.on_changed(myFunc)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Don't use pyplot when embedding in tk. Also the line `canvas = plt.Figure()` isn't used anywhere. Again, let me point you to [the official example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question and showing me how to do it both with and without tkinter. Because I need other widgets and buttons I think I will need tkinter but I might be wrong so I will try without as you have suggested.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have removed  `canvas = plt.Figure()` Thank you so much.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest why not use pyplot? I don't see any real advantage, but I don't see any disadvantage either.

Comment: If your figure is managed by pyplot and by your custom tk canvas at the same time, it will (or at least often does) lead to conflicts.

Comment: What is an alternative to pyplot?

Comment: @MRB The alternative is using `matplotlib.figure.Figure` as the official example shows. However I am not convinced. I've never had a problem with pyplot and tkinter. I recommend you use whichever you want and fix problems later *if* there are any.